# How to store declared variables in a array

Tags: python

I am currently working on a file sorting program and now that I have the selection of the Folders finished I need to assign the right paths to the variables to use them later on to move the files. My code right now looks like this

```
import os
import  promptlib

sourcepath = str()
destpath = str()

pathimg = str()
pathtxt = str()
pathaudio = str()
pathvideo = str()
pathexe = str()
pathzips = str()

def get_paths():
    global sourcepath
    global destpath
    sourcepath = promptlib.Files().dir()+"\\"
    destpath = promptlib.Files().dir()+"\\"

def check_or_create_folder():
    get_paths()
    listToCreate = ["images\\","text documents\\","audio files\\","video files\\","executables\\","zips\\"]
    pathToCreate = destpath+"sortedDownloads\\"
    global paths
    try: os.mkdir(pathToCreate)
    except OSError: return
    for elememt in listToCreate:
        try: os.mkdir(pathToCreate+elememt)
        except OSError: break
```

I thought about storing them in an array and then declaring them element by element maybe something like

```
def check_or_create_folder():
    paths = [global pathimg, global pathtxt]  
    listToCreate = ["images\\","text documents\\","audio files\\","video files\\","executables\\","zips\\"]
    pathToCreate = destpath+"sortedDownloads\\"
    for i in range(len(listToCreate)):
        try: os.mkdir(pathToCreate+listToCreate[i])
            paths[i] = pathToCreate+listToCreate[i]
        except OSError: break
```

but that doesn't work, I tried searching it up but I couldn't find anything so what would be your approach to this problem?
thank you before for answering.
(i am sorry for my English I'm still 15 years old and it's not that good)

Comment: paths = [pathimg, pathtxt] should work

Comment: Note, btw, that in general using globals is a "code smell" -- it implies that you could improve your design to stop doing that. Consider, for example, encapsulating your logic in an object and making what are currently globals instead be member variables. One big advantage of that is that it makes writing a test suite easier, since you can create as many instances of that object as you need to complete your test suite.

Comment: What does `promptlib.Files()` do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables. Instead of using string operations to combine pathes, use `pathlib.Path`.

To store your created folders, just use a list:

```
import promptlib
from pathlib import Path

SUB_FOLDERS = ["images", "text documents", "audio files", "video files", "executables", "zips"]

def get_paths():
    sourcepath = Path(promptlib.Files().dir())
    destpath = Path(promptlib.Files().dir())
    return sourcepath, destpath

def check_or_create_folder():
    sourcepath, destpath = get_paths()
    folders = []
    for folder in SUB_FOLDERS:
        folder = destpath / "sortedDownloads" / folder
        folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        folders.append(folder)
    return sourcepath, folders
```